# Passing a node variable into views filtering

Tags: views, nodes

I have content type called "season", which has a custom field. This field can have two options: Helloween and Christmas. Article content type contains the same field.

I want to create a View, which would sort articles by actualy selected field value of single "season" node. Is this possible in Drupal7?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  You are wanting a [context filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJFMTDuaxy8).

More details about your situation will let me give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already checked this video hours ago, with no help. Output of what i want to do is this: Anythime when user edits single "season" node field to "helloween", every views on a page should show only articles, with value "helloween".